# How to give an empty element some width and height?

Tags: html, css

I have an empty element on my page that I'd like to give some width and height to.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/tzxv5zb3/

As you will see, I've tried giving the element a style attribute with some values for width and height. For example:

```
<span id="element-b" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background-color: #555;"> </span>
```

However, this does nothing.

How to give my empty element (`#element-b`) some width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` is an inline element. Try using `div`, or else add

```
display:block;
```

to your style

Example in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/tzxv5zb3/2/)

Answer (score 5):

spans are inline elements by default, which give you no option to manipulate their dimensions.
Try the following:

```
<span id="element-b" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 20px; background-color: #555;"></span>
```

Comment: Interestingly, `block` (but not `inline-block`) did the trick for me. Still a +1 answer. Thanks!

Comment: inline-block works fine, if it doesn't, then your other CSS might interfere :-) But thanks for the upboat.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Apply the "`display: inline-block;" style to the span.

For old versions of IE, you will need to apply "`zoom: 1;`" INSTEAD of the inline-block property. I'm sorry to say I can't recall what the highest version you need to do this to is, but I know you need it for 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a span is an inline element. For it to respect the width/height rules, you need to make it `block` or `inline-block`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/tzxv5zb3/1/